# PHP Разрешить или запретить подключение к порту при проверке

Tags: php

Мой апач настроен на определенный порт, на этот же порт настроено подключение приложения, каким образом я могу запретить соединение этому приложению по порту в условии?

Comment: https://perishablepress.com/eight-ways-to-blacklist-with-apaches-mod_rewrite/

Comment: Не поняла Вас. Все что мне требуется, это сравнить получаемый хеш, и если хеш приложения не верен то запретить ему соединяться по этому ip\port